# Netbeans Debug error

Tags: java, swing, debugging

I have executed the SDK given by the client for one of my project. I am able to successfully Build the project but whenever I try to Debug It throws me an error - "**Thread AWT-EventQueue-0 stopped at morpho.morphosmart.sdk.demo.MsoConnection. - compiled without debug info.**"
and after this InvocationEvent.java class is opened and cursor point at run() method within dispatch() method.

```
public void dispatch() {
        try {
            if (catchExceptions) {
                try {
                    runnable.run();
                }
                catch (Throwable t) {
                    if (t instanceof Exception) {
                        exception = (Exception) t;
                    }
                    throwable = t;
                }
            }
            else {
                **runnable.run();**// cursor point over here
            }
        } finally {
            finishedDispatching(true);
        }
    }
```

If anyone can help me out in this.. I am stuck over here since last two days without any solution.

Comment: What kind of project do you have: maven, ant, ? Did you reconfigure Netbeans actions for this specific project?

Comment: It is a Swing application.I haven't reconfigured Netbeans actions but other projects can be debug successfully.